# object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I am trying to compile this code that is running, but not compiling.

```
Error Message: Quitting from lines 40-42 (midterm.Rmd) 
Error in data$Y_i1 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> mean
Execution halted
```

**CODE**

````
**c) Using the dataset “potential_outcomes.Rda" from Problem Set 1 (also loaded with this exam on bCourses), calculate the ATE and SE($\hat{ATE}$) using R. For the latter, assume that half of the units will be assigned to the treatment group in the experiment. Is the ATE a parameter or an estimator? How about SE($\hat{ATE}$)?**

```{r}
ATE <- mean(data$Y_i1) - mean(data$Y_i0)
ATE ## Average Treatment Effect
```

```{r}
N1 <- length(data$Y_i1)
N0 <- length(data$Y_i0)
N <- 23 # Half of observations
var1 <- var(data$Y_i1)
var0 <- var(data$Y_i0)
var1N <- var1/N
var0N <- var0/N
SEATE <- sqrt(var1N + var0N)
SEATE ## The Standard Error of the ATE
```

The ATE is a parameter because it describes the box. There is no estimation required. The SE of the ATE on the other hand, approximates the true standard error for the difference in means.
````

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

`object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` means you're trying to subset a function. If you don't set `data`, it will refer to the `data` function from the `utils` package.

```
is.function(data)
#> [1] TRUE
```

So we get the error if we try to use the `$` operator.

```
data$Species
#> Error in data$Species : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

But, if `data` gets set to a data frame, it works.

```
data <- iris

data$Species
#>  [1] setosa     setosa    
#>  [3] setosa     setosa  
#>  ...
```

Comment: For some reason though, even when I rename the data to something else, it still gives me this error. I renamed it sab for example. sab$y_i0 is still giving me the error.